# Sorting vector (c++)

Tags: c++, vector

I have to sort a vector N into M equals parts(M less than N).

But those equal parts have to be in the middle. If I have parts that are not equal i need to put them in the first and/or last element.Difference between first and last has to be minimal. I have managed to make a sort of that function. Function is making new vector(sizeof(M)) and inside stores number of parts from vector N. 
ex. 10/7 vector M [1 1 2 2 2 1 1] 1+1+2+2+2+1+1=10 into 7 parts. Meaning I am taking n or n+1 objects for vector N and storing index in vector M. Values inside do not have to be equal.

Now I am having trouble because my deviations can only be first and last element.
And also i am having problems whit for 
ex. 12/9 because i get M[1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 ] 
but if I can only have first and last as different 
then it should be like M[3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2]

So my question : Is there any better way of making this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int N = 12;     // size of vector
int M = 9;      // numbers of divisions


static void subsizes(int vecSize, int subCount, vector<int> &v)
{
    int baseSize = vecSize / subCount;
    int bumps = vecSize % subCount;
    int i,n=0,nPlus,counterPlus=0,counterN,counterLeft;
    vector<int> temp(subCount);         // for new results
    vector<int> proba(subCount);

    for (i = 0; i < subCount; i++)          //dividing to n, n+1 and placing them in vector
    {
        temp[i]= baseSize + (i < bumps);
    }


    for (i=0; i<subCount; i++)          // finding what numbers are n, n+1
    {
        nPlus=temp[i];
        if(n==0 && n<nPlus){
            n=nPlus;}
    }

    for(i=0; i<subCount;i++)            //counting n, n+1
    {
        if(nPlus==temp[i])counterPlus++;
    }
    counterN=subCount-counterPlus;
    counterLeft=counterPlus-2;


    for(i=0; i<counterPlus/2; i++)          //placing them in right order
        temp[i]=nPlus;
    for(i=counterPlus/2; i<counterPlus/2+counterN; i++)
        temp[i]=n;
    for(i=counterPlus/2+counterN; i<subCount; i++)
        temp[i]=nPlus;

    cout<<endl<<"Divided vector is :"<<endl;            //printing results
    for(i=0; i<subCount;i++)
    {
        int part = temp[i];
        cout<<"At : vector["<<i<<"] nubmer of objects is --- "<<part<<endl;

    }
    putchar('\n');
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<int> vec(N);
    int vecSize = vec.size();       //length of original vector
    int subCount=M;                 //number of sub-vectors parts   

    generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), rand); // filling vector with C function rand()

    cout<<"Vector is [ ";
    for (auto i : vec)          // printing out a vector
    {
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"]"<<endl;

    subsizes(vecSize,subCount,vec);     // calling funciton that divideds and print results


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you give a bit clearer description of your expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: output should be index of start and end of each part of the division. That's why i made new vector to store results in. Input is just size of vector and number of division parts. Because the elements inside are not important just division ratio.

Comment: In your 12/7 example you change the numbers in the input. Is that allowed?

Comment: yes it is i have at the top int M and int N you can change them at any values as long as M<N

Comment: So... is my solution valid? If not please help me understand what it is that you're looking for.

Comment: vector(sizeof(N)) divide into M parts (M<N),  result[0] and result[M-1] can be what ever number of parts but all between numbers have to be equal ex. result[3,1,1,1,1,4] N=11 M=6

Comment: @user3350597 ok, but my answer will now give you `result[1,2,2,2,2,2] N=11 M=6`, since I thought you wanted to maximize the size of sub-parts now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are complicating this, a lot.

If I understand you correctly

- you want to take a vector of size N and divide it into M parts
- Each of the M parts should have the same length
- If there is remaining elements in N, you want to distribute the remainder to extra sub-parts at the beginning and end
- Your output is a vector of the sizes of sub-parts

edit: it seems my assumption of "*you want to distribute the remainder to extra sub-parts at the beginning and end*" was wrong

If that is indeed what you want then you can just do this

```
void subsizes(int vecSize, int subCount, vector<int> &v)
{
    int regular_size = (vecSize+2) / subCount;
    int remainder = vecSize - regular_size * subCount;

    vector<int> sizes(subCount, regular_size);

    int front_remainder = remainder - (remainder / 2);
    int back_remainder = remainder / 2;

    sizes.front() += front_remainder;
    sizes.back() += back_remainder;

    for (int i = 0; i<sizes.size(); i++)
    {
        int part = sizes[i];
        cout << "At : vector[" << i << "] nubmer of objects is --- " << part << endl;

    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: but your a bit off if my subCount = 9 my new vector need's to have 9 elements at size[0] and size[8] i can have more elements but in the middle count has to be equal. when I run your function my vector expanding...

Comment: @user3350597 your example `12/7 M[3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ]` is what I based this on

Comment: @user3350597 I edited it assuming that `12/7` was a typo and was meant to be `12/9`

Comment: yes because if i take 10/6 it should be M[1 2 2 2 2 1] so my new vector has to have 6 elements and when i add all the values it should be = 10 but only on M[0] and M[1] i can have bigger or smaller numbers. middle has to be equal.

Comment: @user why is `10/6` not `[3 1 1 1 1 3]`?

Comment: just because i am dividing them into N and N+1 I have really no idea just taought it would be easier that way

Comment: @user3350597 alright, I added a special case for the case to make as you expected

Comment: tnx a lot i am still learning, now just need to understand why i can write like that....:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have a complete grip on your problem, but it appears that you are allowed to change the elements contained in `vec`. In which case, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
void subsizes(vector<int>& vec)
{
    if(vec.size() > 1) // Don't do anything if there aren't at least 2 elements
    {
        // Get the sum of all the elements,
        // but we're going to be adding back in 1s in every element but the last
        // so subtract (vec.size() - 1) from this total.
        // This is done by initializing accumulate to 1 - vec.size()
        int last = accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1 - vec.size());

        // Now put 1s in all the elements
        fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);

        // Change the last element to the value accumulated in last
        vec.back() = last;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just have to divide the vector into parts what elements are inside in not important. So for ex. sizeof(vec)=10 number_of_division_parts=6

Comment: new divided_vector[0] and dividev_vector[last] can be what ever number but all in the middle has to be equal... and that accumulate i am not strong whit templates i will look it over

Comment: @user3350597 Added some comments in to assist with understanding

Comment: yes but if i am understanding it right you are not dividing vector into parts in this code... and i need to divide a vector size of 10 for example into vector size of 6. So I am saying M[1 2 2 2 2 1] at M[0] I am saving 1 element form vector N at M[1] I am saving 2 and so on...